# S3 presigned url fails when large files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a presigned that works fine for any small file.

When I try to upload larger files, I get ACCESS DENIED in the post without any other message in the body.

The funny thing about it is that if I keep trying, after a few denied hits it works. It is totally random ...

When access is not denied, the condition works by giving the correct error return with a message when the file is larger than 100mb..but the problem is that good part of the posts get denied...

This denied happens in the post for the address of amazon, so I dont have acess to any log of it...

The same POST & SCRIPT:

OK FILE:
[image]

ACCESS DENIED:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
const S3 = new AWS.S3({
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: region
});


const params = {
    Expires: linkExpiresSecs,
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Conditions: [
        ["content-length-range", 1, 104857600]
    ],
    Fields: {
        key: keyFile
    }
};


const response = await S3.createPresignedPost(params);
```

Comment: Could it be that the `linkExpiresSecs` value is too short?

Answer (score 1):

i think the validity of the link expires before the file is downloaded for larger files.
As for the behavior that sometimes the download succeeds, that could be due to network situation e.g. less congestion. or some part of the file was previously cached.