# AWS presigned URL fails when the video is longer than 1 minute

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, pre-signed-url

I tried creating a presigned URL for two videos in the same s3 bucket manually and I've set the expiration date to 7 days :

The first one (47,3 MO and 20 seconds long) is working perfectly.

[First video url output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4114U.jpg)

The second video (82,3 MO and 6 minutes long) is not working : It shows no error in the console

[Second video url output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZeVr.jpg)

It is the same issue even when I use a lambda function to generate the presigned URLS.

[My lambda function code in NodeJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l0HO.jpg)

I found this issue that can help me but it's not solved either :

[S3 presigned url fails when large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63302766/s3-presigned-url-fails-when-large-files)

Comment: I would check that the content type of each object in S3 is correct e.g. video/mp4. I would use curl or wget to retrieve both files outside of a browser and ensure that a) they both download completely (check file size) and b) they are both playable afterwards (with VLC or QuickTime etc.)

Comment: PS you can't typically use AWS Lambda to generate a pre-signed URL that is valid for 7 days. The expiration will be the minimum of what you requested and the remaining time that the Lambda function's IAM role-based credentials are valid (12 hours). Unless the Lambda function also has access to (long-term) IAM User credentials and uses those to pre-sign the URL, of course.

Comment: I did check both videos content type and tested them they are both the same and work fine on different media players. 

Thank you so much for your answer I will create an access key to my lambda function to garantie the 7 day validity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it's the video's problem. the videos I was using were timelapes converted to MP4 and I guess the format wasn't right that's why it's not supported by S3